# VB conversion for C# Razor Syntax - MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

can anyone tell me what the VB equivalent of this is please:

```
@model DateTime

Using Date Template 

@Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:d}", Model.ToShortDateString()), 
  new { @class = "datefield", type = "date"  })
```

I tried:

```
@model DateTime
```

Using Date Template

```
@Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:d}", Model.ToShortDateString()), New With {Key .class = "datefield", Key .type = "date"})
```

...but that errored with:
NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
Object variable or With block variable not set.

It's from the tutorial: [Using the HTML5 and jQuery UI Datepicker Popup Calendar with ASP.NET MVC - Part 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc-part-4)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of @model, can you try ModelType like below,

```
 @ModelType DateTime

 @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", New With {.id = item.ID})
```

Thanks

Deepu

Answer (score 0):

Can you just make sure, you are sending NOT NULL instance of Model to the view from the controller? Rest everything seems ok to me.
Ex:

```
Function Index() As ActionResult
        ViewData("Message") = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!"

        Return View(New Employee()) 'See the : New Employee()'
End Function
```